# mono 3.2.8 (or 3.4) installation on ubuntu 12.04 help needed

Tags: 12.04, mono

I'm new in Linux world

I tried  to install mono `3.2.8` and `3.4` on Ubuntu 12.04 but had no success.

When I use `apt-get` command to install `mono` I get an older version of mono.

Can someone direct me to a guide or explain me how I can install mono 3.4?

Comment: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14089/please-can-people-format-code-properly

Answer (score 1):

This should install the latest version:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mono-complete
```

Comment: when i preform the last command i get:
root@localhost:~# sudo apt-get install mono-complete
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done


The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mono-complete : Depends: mono-devel (= 4.0.1.44-0xamarin1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: mono-4.0-service (= 4.0.1.44-0xamarin1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libmono-cil-dev (= 4.0.1.44-0xamarin1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mono-complete : Depends: mono-devel (= 4.0.1.44-0xamarin1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: mono-4.0-service (= 4.0.1.44-0xamarin1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libmono-cil-dev (= 4.0.1.44-0xamarin1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the newest version of mono on Ubuntu 12.04, there is a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40791968/2295648